# Flash with PHP Integration: Variable error

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

I'm starting to learn how to integrate flash with php files and I'm having trouble with the retrieving of variables.

Here's my AS3 code:

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, varsLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest("http://localhost/flash.php")); 

function varsLoaded (event:Event):void {
    trace(loader.data); // sample text

}
```

And my PHP file goes something like this:

```
<?php

    $txt = "sample text";
    print "myVar = $txt";

?>
```

I changed the value of myVar but the changed value does not apply. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AS3 Resetting UrlLoader Cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448219/as3-resetting-urlloader-cache)

Comment: Your problem is that the response is being cached, see this possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14448219/4347580